# Set condition to populate a "space" in NSString

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I'm using an openPanel to populate a textField with the selected path in the panel. Is there a way to set a condition that specifies if there is a space in the path string, populate (replace) it with a "\" ?

For example:

/Volumes/My Folder ... should be ...

/Volumes/My\Folder

Thanks.

Comment: *'a condition that specifies if there is a space'*?? Do you want to check the string for and replace white space characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're looking for.. however, this is how you would replace white space characters with a backslash (and thereby creating an invalid path....) in an `NSString`:

> NSString myStr = [originagStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\\"];

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you're after when you say "set a condition", are you trying to replace spaces in a string or specialise a text field so that it displays spaces as backslashes?

You will find all the methods you need to replace spaces in the [`NSString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) - look at the section entitled "Replacing Substrings".

If you're trying to specialise the text field you'll want to look at formatters - read the [`NSFormatter` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

HTH